# How can I launch straight into multiplayer?

Tags: titanfall-2

Many games offer launch options to skip the intro movies and launch straight into the multiplayer menu.

Is there something similar for Titanfall 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there are a few launch options you can add but none that launch straight into multiplayer. Here is what I found:

- -high: Launch the game with high CPU priority. (actually it may cause problems).
- -novid: Skip the intro logos.
- -nomenuvid: Disable main menu background video.
- -fullscreen: Launch the game in fullscreen mode.
- -windowed: Launch the game in windowed mode.
  -noborder: Launch the game in borderless mode. Combine with -windowed to get borderless fullscreen.
- -height/-width : Set the resolution of the game. Use this if your resolution is capped to a low value in the in-game options.
- +cl_showfps 1: Shows FPS in the top right corner.
- +cl_showpos 2: Show information about your player's position, such as their current velocity, in the top left corner.
- +m_rawinput 1: Enable raw mouse input.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/titanfall/comments/59ztd2/usefull_titanfall_2_shortcut_arguments/

Comment: I wish the xb1 had some of these options